# Use "length without unit" as scale parameter

Tags: scaling, calculations, lengths

I'd like to have a number variable in Latex to be used for the scale parameter in an includegraphics command (for example, to let all finite state machine pictures be scaled to the same size). This works if I just use a makro like this:

```
\newcommand{\fsmScale}{0.7}
\includegraphics[scale=\fsmScale]{...}
```

But sometime a figure might be a little to large (or so), and I might want to do something like this:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.9\fsmScale]{...}
```

But this only works for lengths, and lengths have units (pt, mm etc.) that do not work as a scale.

This is a minimal non-working example of what I'd like to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{0.7}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.9\mylength]{...}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to do that or something similar?

Comment: I think your plan is scratched. You want to give a universal rule (scale), but want to be able to change single instances. Do all scales by hand.

Comment: That might be true - but I'm at the end of a quite big project... This might not be the nicest way to do this in general, but it's certainly the easiest way without changing too much of the given stuff. (I don't want to set single values by hand as I still want to be able to scale them altogether. Also, the additional correction is supposed to be minimal, like 0.97 or so.)

Comment: Also, there certainly are other applications for my problem.

Comment: if you want them all the same size better to use height= than scale=, but you can do the arithmetic you suggest by `[scale=\mylenth,scale=0.9]`

Comment: That's actually working!! Thank you so much - didn't know that. If you post an answer, I'll definitely accept it.

Comment: Almost always what you need really is to adapt the size of a picture to the document layout and not the opposite,  so the best solution *usually* is not `scale`. It will be `width` and/or `height`with **relative** lengths, for instance: `[width=.8\linewith, height=.3\textheight,keepaspectratio]`.

Comment: @Fran: I don't agree! I have, for example, many figures with finite state machines- which just looks silly if they all have different node sizes etc.

Comment: @lukas.coenig I remarked  *usually* thinking in this type of exceptions , but if  you  need to reduce the scale often, at the end you will face the  same problem.

Comment: Actually I hope I'll be able to avoid it after all. I shifted some things around, and now it's fitting without resizing. But still, I feel like this is a legitimate question. I create lots of exercise sheets for lectures where it's not important that they look "perfect", but they should look "nice". And when you have a picture that is just slightly oversized, this is - for me - just the way to go...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Please consider turning your comment to an answer. I will add one myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unfortunatly calculate the product of two non-integer factors and get a factor using (La)TeX, at least not directly. One must be a dimension and the result will be a dimension. However, LaTeX has an internal macro `\rem@pt` to remove the trailing `pt` from dimensional values to turn them to factors. The multiplication can be done using eTeX `\dimexpr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\myfactor}{0.7}

\newcommand{\scaletomyfactor}[1]{%
    \csname rem@pt\expandafter\endcsname\the\dimexpr #1\dimexpr\myfactor pt\relax\relax
}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=\scaletomyfactor{0.7}]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

If `\myfactor` is a LaTeX length register you can change `\dimexpr\myfactor pt\relax` to simply `\myfactor`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them all the same size better to use `height=` than `scale=`, but you can do the arithmetic you suggest by

```
\includegraphics[scale=\mylength,scale=0.9]{...}
```